# Keeping DRY between Javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, dry

Say you've got a menu that toggles open and closed with a button. My standard way of going about this would be to write the CSS for a closed menu, and write Javascript that specifies (or animates to) an open menu state.

Lately I've gotten into Active.js, a client-side MVC framework. It provides for view classes with builders for making DOM fragments, and those fragments can be given methods that handle things like animation and DOM state.

Something feels wonky about describing the initial state in CSS, and then describing alternate states in JavaScript. Without animation, it would be sensible to just do it all in CSS and just use javascript to add or remove DOM classes.

My other idea is to describe all of the states (folded, unfolded, red, green) of a DOM object in JSON (rather than CSS) and give my ActionView object methods for animating between those states. Is anybody doing this? Other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As far as animation goes, it wouldn't be a violation of DRY to have basic styling in CSS and then the animation or styling you can't achieve in pure CSS in javascript because you still don't have any repetition if done right. If you think its a more "pure" way to do things you can try to keep more of the styling in javascript or CSS, but those are just the languages you are using and if you consider them both expressions of the same underlying DOM its entirely appropriate to use the more expressive or compatible language wherever needed.

I typically take CSS as far as it will go and then start using jQuery to do the things that CSS can't handle or are not cross browser, like animations.