# Can Ruby hashes be included in Sass and CoffeeScript, allowing data to be shared?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, sass, compass-sass

I am wondering if a ruby hash can be shared between Sass and CoffeeScript with a minimum of fuss.

I've looked around for an answer to this but found nothing conclusive. Sources, such as the [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import) for [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#data_types), talk about how to link files of the same type and how to manipulate data structures within the language, but don't touch on whether data can be imported from elsewhere, or whether ruby code can be interpreted in someway - the only similar thing I can think of is compass using a .rb file for it's config.

My instinct suggests this is (or should) be possible, both languages are Ruby-like and capable of interpreting hashes.

As this is a practical problem I've faced several times (DRYing up pre-processed front end code, but also providing the same values for back-end processing, such as generating an SVG in an HTML template) but never solved in a really clean way I would accept a solution that involved using Rails.

Please note, I am quite specific about this relating to the *pre-compilation stage* of front end asset production, namely *Sass* and *CoffeeScript*. Answers which involve CSS, JavaScript or require a browser are not what I'm looking for.

**Extra bits**

I've decided to add an example, here are three definitions of the same data as key value pairs:

[Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318912/whats-the-proper-hash-syntax-in-ruby-2-0)

```
colours = { brandBackground: '#f00', brandForeground: '#00f', brandText: '#0f0' }
colours[:brandBackground]
```

[Sass Map](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#maps)

```
$colours: ( brandBackground: '#f00', brandForeground: '#00f', brandText: '#0f0' )
map-get($colours, brandBackground)
```

[CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#literals)

```
colours = { brandBackground: '#f00', brandForeground: '#00f', brandText: '#0f0' }
colours.brandBackground
```

Coffeescript and Ruby hash definitions are identical, Sass is very close ... if this can work then colours (or any other variable) could be defined in one place then used throughout the front and back end by any code.

Comment: I'm not clear on what exactly you want, but files ending with .erb are erb templates.

Comment: i added some sources which cover the sort of things I know are possible, but not whether or not it's possible to include ruby - I'm imagining a plugin might do it, but I haven't found that

Comment: @DaveNewton - I want to share a ruby hash pre-compilation between coffee-script and sass, two languages with a ruby-like syntax

Comment: Neither will magically understand Ruby. If you want Ruby, make them erb templates.

Comment: @DaveNewton - sounds promising, how might one do that - yes, I understand they won't magically interpret, hence my acceptance that there may be some intermediate stage, however, there is value in doing this

Comment: Stick an `.erb` at the end of the file; I'm not sure what other mechanics would be involved. The most I've done with this with CSS-like artifacts are storing some constants so they can be used across back- and front-ends.

Comment: @DaveNewton interesting, tbh that sounds like an answer, and SO is complaining about our comment chat - I'm going to investigate, perhaps I'll answer my own question!

Comment: Could you care to explain the use-case for this question? I understand the example is hypothetical because I could not imagine for the life of me why I would need actual colours in ruby or coffeescript. So coffeescript <-> ruby, I can get, the sass part not so much. Just curious.

Comment: @nathanvda - I've encountered situations where values are used in sass and javascript, for example, you might want to tie behaviour and styling to the same breakpoint - it's valuable enough for [this to be written](http://viget.com/extend/sharing-data-between-sass-and-javascript-with-json); and for [this to be asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898992/keeping-dry-between-javascript-and-css) - I was thinking that potentially Ruby / coffeescript could offer the cleanest solution

Comment: @nathanvda - it would be useful just to know, there'll be cases I can't think of and the endgame would be sensibly DRYed code, therefore good!

Comment: I would leave all potentially dynamic data out of the assets (sass /js/css) and get it in the page another way.

Comment: the data itself would be static in the assets (e.g. brand-primary-colour) but at the pre-compile stage it would be possible to change it in one place, so it isn't dynamic in js or css, but it is in the sass or coffeescript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can turn your CoffeeScript and SASS into ERB templates which will be preprocessed (and thus you can use all awesome Ruby's possibilities in them). There is a little post that describes this: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/dont-repeat-your-ruby-constants-in-javascript.

**Update**

Add this code into `lib/shared_assets_data.rb`:

```
module SharedAssetsData
  def self.colors_hash
    { brandBackground: '#f00', brandForeground: '#00f', brandText: '#0f0' }
  end

  def self.sassify(hash)
    hash.map do |key, value|
      "#{key}: '#{value}'"
    end.join(', ').prepend('( ').concat(' )')
  end

  def self.coffefy(hash)
    hash.map do |key, value|
      "#{key}: '#{value}'"
    end.join(', ').prepend('{ ').concat(' }')
  end
end
```

Then to enable autoloading `lib` directory add this line to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib)
```

After that you can do following:

```
# screen.sass.erb
$colours: <%= SharedAssetsData.sassify(SharedAssetsData.colors_hash) %>
body
  background: map-get($colours, brandBackground)

# screen.coffee.erb
colours = <%= SharedAssetsData.coffefy(SharedAssetsData.colors_hash) %>
console.log colours.brandBackground
```

Comment: would be nice to see an example in the answer, especially seen as there's a bounty going, and because link-rot

Comment: i believe coffee-script could use the original hash, they're identical, without needing coffeefication?

Comment: I tried that, but Ruby prints hashes in Ruby 1.8.7 style notation: {:a=>1}

Comment: yeah the Ruby hash in my example is the newer syntax

Comment: Currently `sassify` method uses a hash as a parameter. Because of this code in assets looks a bit clumsy (constant is duplicated). If you plan to store all shared hashes in that class, the class could be improved to provide more readability. I can do it if you'd like.

Answer (score -1):

I think your best bet is to use `gon`. [Gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) is a gem that allows you to pass ruby variables to javascript/coffeescript. From there you can inline a style that makes use of the ruby hash.

Sass/CSS are really only about styles, and while Sass can have variables and do math, you shouldn't use it as a store for more complex data structures, this will make you code very difficult to maintain. Data storage and transport just isn't the job of Sass.

So, as for gon. Try something like this in your controller:

```
gon.ruby_hash = {key: value}
```

now in you coffeescript:

```
gon.ruby_hash
```

You'll be able to access the hash by calling gon.ruby_variable_name.

Comment: I'm not intending to store data in sass, but to use data stored elsewhere in there in order to keep that data defined in a place where it is re-usable by other pre-compiled assets

Comment: In that case you need to define a variable in Sass, and access it from your coffeescript.

For clarification:
Where is the data stored?
What is it for?
Does it ever change?

Comment: the data would be stored with the pre-compiled files (though I suppose it could be anywhere); it would store values that could be shared between compiled front end assets, such as breakpoints; yes, it could change, part of the point is that it's easier to change shared values in a robust way;

Comment: also, I would expect this to be independent of any Ruby MVC structure, so there wouldn't be controllers storing anything

Comment: In that case write a script that runs before compilation that generates a variables.scss file. Require that file in your application.scss. You could use sass maps http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#maps, but I have to stress that this isn't what sass is for. You should really consider other options like YAML, or some other plain ruby method of pushing data to your coffee/sass/front-end.

Comment: i actually take back the comment about controllers, but still, I'm not talking about using sass to store the source of the variables, sass would interpret the source of the variables and so would coffeescript (ideally)

Comment: I edited my question with an example, maybe that helps clear up what I mean :-)

Comment: Hum... I'm not sure there's a good off the shelf solution for that exact use case.